# How can I delete an Attribute value in Xml using java code?

Tags: java, xml

I am working with an xml file and I want to delete a portion of an attribute value, but not the whole attribute.

For  example:

```
<parent>
<variable dim = "dimension1 dimension2" value = " variableValue"/>
</parent>
```

I want to delete only ' dimension2 '  from the 'dim' attribute.

How can I do that.?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which library you use to parse XML with.  I personally like JDOM because its much more straight forward for working with XML.  If you were to do that it would be:

```
Element element = ...;
Attribute attribute = element.getAttribute("dim");
attribute.setValue( attribute.getValue().replace("dimension2", "") );
```

It'd be very similar with other XML processes.

http://www.jdom.org/

If you are parsing with SAX it's more complicated because you have to process the whole document, and modify it while you are parsing it with SAX.  You probably are just using DOM, but just to cover most cases.  If you're using a pull parser it's roughly the same as DOM.